# System Preferences locked even after entering password

Tags: macos, system-settings

I am using OS X El Capitan. For some reason, I can no longer unlock the preferences in System Preferences panes although I still appear as an admin. When I enter my password for authentication it simply goes back to the locked mode again. How can I fix this?

Comment: How long does it take to lock again? Does it not open in the first place, or does it stay, and then after a short while locks again? Also, I don't know if **Repair Disk Permissions** In **Disk Utility** could work...

Comment: it doesn't unlock at all. And I don't remember having changed the system preferences lately

Comment: @TheBro21 Repair Disk Permissions is no longer available in Disk Utility.

Comment: a working solution can be found here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7260492